# Google Sheets save the style of sheet while merging it to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to save the styles of the sheets when I combine them into a mainsheet. Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() 
 {
   var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("MainSheet");
   
   if (newSheet != null) {
        activeSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(newSheet);
    }

   newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
   newSheet.setName("MainSheet");
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const allSheets = ss.getSheets();
   const allSheets_names=allSheets.map(sheet=>sheet.getSheetName())  
   const dataRange = "A1:M";
   const checkRange = "A1:A";
   const neededSheets = ["Cats", "Dogs"];
   const filteredListOfSheetsNames = [];       
  neededSheets.forEach(function(ns){  
    var i = neededSheets.indexOf(ns);
    filteredListOfSheetsNames[i]=[];
    allSheets_names.forEach( (as,index) => {                            
      if (as.indexOf(ns)>-1){
        filteredListOfSheetsNames[i].push(as);
        }
      }
    )
    const filteredListOfSheets  =  filteredListOfSheetsNames[i].map(name =>ss.getSheetByName(name));  
    var array = [];
    filteredListOfSheets.forEach(function(sheet){var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),13).getValues(); array.push(values);});

    array = [].concat.apply([],array);
    if(array.length > 0){
      newSheet.getRange(1,i*13+1, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Currently, I get all the information correctly. On one side of the mainsheet I get sheets that contain a word "dog" in them and on another side of the mainsheet I get the sheets that contain a word "cat". The issue is that the font, colors disappear after I combine all the sheets. How should I keep the styles when combining the sheets?

Here is an example of the MainSheet on how it should look like, but it should also take all of the styles from the sheets.
[image: Example of MainSheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `copyTo` to copy the formatting from one sheet to another. See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options).

Here is a minimal example based off of your script that copies the formatting to `mainSheet` from sheets `Cats` and `Dogs`. This script assumes that the script will be attached to the spreadsheet on which it is to operate, which you're likely already doing.

```
function myFunction() {
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MainSheet");
   const neededSheets = ["Cats", "Dogs"];  
  
   mainSheet.clearFormats().clear() // clear formatting and values on main sheet
   
   
  for(var i=0; i<neededSheets.length; i++) 
     {
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(neededSheets[i]) ;
      var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),13).getValues(); 
      mainSheet.getRange(1,i*13+1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
       
      var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),13) // define the range that has the formatting you want to copy
      var targetRange = mainSheet.getRange(1,i*13+1, values.length, values[0].length) // define the range that you want to copy the formatting to
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true}) // copy the format
      
     }
}
```